# How to go from Bangkok to Koh Samui without flight?

Tags: thailand

How could I get from Bangkok to Koh Samui without flying?

- Where should I take a vehicle from (Ekkamai?, Saitaimai?, Mochit?)?
- Which vehicle company has the largest safest vans/busses with largest sitting space?
- Which vehicle company does at least two stops in the drive? (It can be very frustrating to sit down 5-6 hours without stops)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're just asking how to get from Bangkok to Koh Samui without flying to Koh Samui. If that's accurate, can I suggest you edit your question (at the very least, the title of your question) to say *that*? Because your reasons for wanting to avoid the airport aren't especially relevant, but the current focus on explaining that you see the operators as a monopoly rather distracts from your actual question and makes it sound more like a political rant.

Comment: Or are you ruling out flying entirely, regardless of the operator? You already mention taking a bus via Surat Thani. Flights from Bangkok to Surat Thani seem to be operated by several airlines under different ownership, and can be had for significantly less than the 5k-6k baht you mentioned for flights to Koh Samui (although still more than a bus). Clarifying what it is that you *do* want (rather than *why* you don't want something else) will probably make the question more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Hi @ChrisH ; edited.

Comment: FWIW, Thai Airways used to fly to Samui twice daily, but they stopped flights in Sep 2020 due to COVID.  Also, Bangkok Airways built & paid for Samui Airport and pretty much put the island in the map, so dismissing them as an evil monopoly is a bit glib.

Answer (score 2):

12Go usually showing most of the options, I ruled out non-flights for you.

https://12go.asia/en/travel/bangkok/koh-samui?vehclasses=train,bus,ferry

They don't have many packed joints right now, I guess some ferry companies are not running. You basically can take a bus (from either Southern or Morchit) or a train. Train is preferable, you can get a sleeper to Surat, short bus to Donsak and then a ferry of your choice (they are interconnected).

In fact if you look for [Bangkok to Suratthani](https://12go.asia/en/travel/bangkok/surat-thani?vehclasses=train,bus) and [Surattani to Samui](https://12go.asia/en/travel/surat-thani/koh-samui?vehclasses=bus,ferry) separately, you find a lot more options, but you have to find what better for your join. Mind that trains are usually delayed.